# `Express.session` gives a warning on leaking memory

Tags: typescript, nestjs

When I run my `docker-compose-prod.yaml` file to spin up a docker image and a NestJS application within, it gives me such a warning:

```
nestjs-prod   | Warning: connect.session() MemoryStore is not
nestjs-prod   | designed for a production environment, as it will leak
nestjs-prod   | memory, and will not scale past a single process.
```

I am well aware of what is memory leakage. I wonder what is the best practice to resolve this issue.

Comment: Ignore the warning.

Comment: What is it you're looking to "solve" here?